# Json unmarshalling in GO

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal a json response from the server into various types, but I
am not finding how to do it.

The types which work are :-

```
type ServerResponse struct {
  Total int
  Data  []User
}

type User struct {
  Name  string
  Age   int
}
```

and I can successfully unmarshal the json and receive the expected User type.

What I want to do is handle various server responses and convert after the
fact. eg.

```
type ServerResponse struct {
  Total int
  Data  []ServerItem
}

type User struct {
  ServerItem
  Name  string
  Age   int
}

type Book struct {
  ServerItem
  Name      string
  Author    string
}
```

Then use either User(response.Data) or response.Data.(User) to make it a
concrete type so that later functions type check correctly.

Please could anyone let me know where to start looking to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you provide an example of JSON response you want to unmarshal / parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done easily. Just decode to `map[string]interface{}` and create your stuff from this.

Comment: Thanks, @Volker. That was the conclusion I had come to, but I was hoping that I had missed something somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote a simple program that parses json http://play.golang.org/p/51eiswgznR.

You may also want to read the encoding/json docs http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

Comment: Thanks very much for the example @mawenbao, I'm going to implement something like that for the configuration of my application.